# Acrescentar um número num array dá problema de índice

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, regressão

Eu já tentei de tudo e não consegui acrescentar o número 1 no fim da lista previsores. Dá o seguinte erro:

> new_inputs[i] = np.append(inputs[i],one[i])
>
> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Não posso usar *append* normal porque é um array e usando a biblioteca *Numpy* também não funciona. Preciso colocar o valor 1 na última coluna de cada amostra.

Esse é o código:

```
base = pd.read_excel("TSLA.xlsx", sheet_name=4)
base = base.dropna()
base_treinamento = base.iloc[:, 1:2].values

previsores = []
preco_real = []
for i in range(90, 753):
    previsores.append(base_treinamento[i-90:i, 0])
    preco_real.append(base_treinamento[i, 0])

inputs = np.array(previsores)

one =np.ones(len(previsores))
new_inputs=[]
for i in range(len(previsores)):
    new_inputs[i] = np.append(inputs[i], one[i] )
```

E o link pro arquivo: [TSLA](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z0prvb83gj6uhoy/TSLA.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inputs` e `one` são arrays de estruturas diferentes (`inputs` pode ser visto como uma lista de listas e `one` apenas como uma lista), por isso seu loop não vai funcionar. Aliás, você nem precisa do loop, uma vez que você não deve usar `append` e sim `concatenate`. Faça assim:

```
one = np.ones((len(previsores), 1))
new_inputs = np.concatenate([inputs, one], axis = 1)
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeito, valeu!